# Declare variable in for loop JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a small question about for loop in Js:
Why i have to write:

```
for (let i; i < 10; i++) {}
```

Meanwhile, the code will run correctly if i write:

```
for (i; i < 10; i++) {}
```

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If it works doesn't mean that you should.
If you use ```let``` then the variable is __declared within the scope__ you are in __for ex:-function__. If you don't use ```let```, the variable bubbles up through the layers of scope until it encounters a variable by the given name or the global object where it then attaches itself. It is then very similar to a global variable and __*it can overwrite existing variables*__ which would break your entire code and is very dangerous as it might then become very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It works because JavaScript allows using undeclared variables. But if you enable strict mode using `'use strict'`, it will not work as you never declared `i`. It’s better to use the first example you provided.